# Core Data: Bad Access Error upon Execute Fetch

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchrequest

In the commit of UITableView I delete an object using the following code:

```
[_context deleteObject:[_StudiessList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSError *error; 
if (![_context save:&error]) {
    // Handle error
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error series %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
 [self LoadData]; // bad access fire here
```

where `LoadData` is the function to refill the table view

Its code is:

```
iPaxeraAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iPaxeraAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Studies" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"StudyDate" ascending:YES] autorelease]]; 
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error;
@try {  
    // error done here exactly at fetch 
    self.StudiessList = [_context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];  
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(e);
}
[fetchRequest release];
[StudiessList retain];
```

`LoadData` crashes upon `executeFetchRequest:`

Comment: You are also leaking `StudiesList`. Sense it is presumably a retained property the call to `self.StudiessList` already retains the returned array. Sending another retain to it will cause it to leak if it is not balanced with yet another release in addition to the one sent in dealloc.

Comment: Your code will be easier to read if you follow the styling conventions. Only Framework names, class names and constants should start with a capital letter. (Also, StudiessList is spelled wrong). So `StudiessList` should be `studiesList` and `LoadData` should be `loadData`. Following the conventions will make your code easier for others to read. Apple has a style guide buried somewhere. You should try to track it down and follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably here:

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"StudyDate" ascending:YES] autorelease]];
```

By attaching an explicit autorelease you set up a circumstance in which the sort descriptor may be deallocated while it is still needed. When the fetch goes to grab the sort descriptor, it crashes because the object is not there.

Explicit autoreleases can be problematical because they are intimately linked to the draining of the memory pool of the immediate scope they are defined in. Although many people use autorelease casually, you should really only use it when you are returning a value from a method because autorelease tells, the runtime, "I am completely done with this object and I don't care what happens to it." If you are not done with the object, then you will have problems.

Using an implicit autorelease from a convenience method eliminates this problem because the autorelease is issued in another scope e.g. the class object holding the convenience method. It then enters the local scope and can be retained without having to worry about an autorelease in the local scope killing it.

Try:

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"StudyDate " ascending:YES]];
```

... and see if that resolves the crash.

Comment: could u tell me when will I release it and should I say [sortDescriptor retain];

Comment: The sortDescriptorWithKey: is a convenience method that returns an autoreleased object so you don't have to release it. However, it is autoreleased in a different scope so it may prevent the problems you are having now.

Comment: I removed it but it raise the same error  [_StudiessList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; it raise the following error -[_PFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance